# Não consigo deletar chave no dbm

Tags: banco-de-dados, python, python-3.x

Fiz um programinha básico para armazenar alguns dados e estou com problemas caso o usuário escolha a opção de deletar alguma chave do dicionário armazenado. A função que apaga os dados no meu programa é essa:

```
def EraseData(name):
'''
Apaga uma chave do dicionário do banco de dados.
'''
db = dbm.open('data.db', 'c')
del db[name]
db.close()
```

Quando vou pesquisar as entradas no meu banco de dados vejo que NADA foi apagado. Simplesmente não funciona.

Esse é o link de todo o meu código do `GIT`:https://github.com/JeffersonCarvalh0/Armazenamento-de-dados/blob/master/armazenamento.py

Comment: Acho que aqui pode ajudar você. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844672/delete-an-element-from-a-dictionary

Comment: Mas eu não quero manter o banco de dados e apagar de uma cópia, eu quero mesmo é mudá-lo. No entanto, mesmo usando o `del` eu não consigo. Percebi que pelo modo interativo, quando eu executo exatamente as mesmas linhas que tenho na função, eu consigo apagar a chave, mas pela função não funciona.

Comment: Então, você precisa detalhar mais o seu erro. A função está correta, funciona perfeitamente. Seu programa, entretanto, tem alguns erros não funcionando devidamente. Arrumei os erros e tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Tem certeza que o problema é esse que você expôs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu disse, você precisa detalhar mais o seu erro. A função que você criou funciona perfeitamente, mas, no entanto, há alguns errinhos no seu programa que a impedem de funcionar.

Primeiro, erros de sintaxe, na função CheckRg, endente o if corretamente.

Segundo, na função ShowList, está dando que db não é iterável. Sendo assim, itere sobre as chaves do banco:

```
for key in db.keys():
    ...
```

Por fim, a parte que de fato impede a função EraseData de funcionar é o levantamento da exceção `FileAlreadyExists` na função SearchData. A exceção está sendo levantada antes de se fechar a conexão com o banco de dados. Isso impede que a função EraseData abra uma nova conexão (gerando uma nova exceção) e delete definitivamente uma entrada.

Logo:

```
def SearchData(nome):
    db = dbm.open('data.db', 'c')
    if name in db:
        db.close()
        raise FileAlreadyExists
```

Depois que isso foi feito, a função funciona perfeitamente. Caso contrário, precisamos de mais detalhes da execução do seu programa.

Comment: Ah, agora sim... quanto aos erros de sintaxe, não sei de onde saíram, pois ontem quando criei esse tópico, o código estava sem erros (deve ter sido devido a alguma confusão que eu fiz enquanto tentava passar esse código pro `GIT`, pois ainda estou aprendendo a mexer nele).
    Quanto à minha função `ShowList`, aqui ela funciona perfeitamente.
    Por último, eu realmente não tinha visto esse problema na função `SearchData`. Fiz a correção sugerida e agora o programa funciona sem problemas. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Testei aqui, e usando direto no modo interativo funciona o `del`  (apesar de a documentçção desse módulo ser bem fraquinha e nem mencionar o `del` e nem ele aparecer no `dir` do objeto dbm).

A minha hipótese é a seguinte: você tem essa funão `EraseData` e nela você abre, modifica e fecha o banco - no entanto, acredito que se o mesmo banco estiver aberto enquanto você faz essas açoes, pode ser que quando ele feche a outra cópia do banco que está aberta as chaves que existam lá é que fiquem valendo. Você tem o banco aberto numa variável no contexto que chama o `EraseData` (ou em outra thread/contexto qualquer?)

Eu não acredito que esse módulo vá funcionar bem abrindo mais de uma conexão ao mesmo tempo ao mesmo arquivo - nem que tenha sido pensado para funcionar assim: minha sugestão é abrir esse banco no início do programa, e só fecha-lo na saída. (use uma cláusula `try...finally` para garantir que a função `close` seja chamada - e, ou passe a instância do banco para todas as funções que o acessam, ou crie uma classe em que um dos atributos é a instância do banco - e promova todas as funções para métodos dessa classe, ou simplesmente deixe um avariável global com a instância do banco  (não é tão ruim em Python como em C ou outras linguagens, porque variáves "globais" não são realmente "globais" - são variáveis de módulo com vigência apenas no namespace daquele módulo)